# Border is not included in width calculation for media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

which is causing things to look sloppy.

There is a div which expand to 100%, but the right border is cut off.

See the dev site here - it is under Feed

https://frozen-dusk-2587.herokuapp.com/

Here in image of me toggling the border using Chrome Dev Tools:

[image]

and here it is with me toggling on the border:

[image]

Comment: neither is padding. is there a question?

Comment: Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: Try: `$('#at_view').removeClass('shadow');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even such basic things as the box model can be modified using CSS Rules.

See

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

to change the default behavior of the box model:

```
#at_view{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behaviour for all `box-sizing:content-box` elements, which is the default value for all elements.  add `box-sizing:border-box;` to `#at_view`.  This causes the browser to include border and padding in relative width calculations.

Answer (score 1):

If you define an element with a width of 100% and also a border, the border is added to the 100% so this makes the total width more than 100% which is causing your problem (read up on the css box-model: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

So one solution is that you could change the width of `#at_view` to less than 100%, try 90-95% - until things look right.

Or to be very specific, you can define `#at_view` width as 100% and subtract the border using calc():

```
#at_view { 
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

(Subtracting 20px, since it looks like 20px is the width being added by the border, as the border is 10px --> 10px on the left + 10px on the right = 20px.)

Comment: Also I'm not sure why you have the element defined as ```display: inline-block``` - that is affecting its margins in a way I'm not sure you want. Defining the element as ```display: block``` instead and the width as ```width: calc(100% - 10px);``` works to get it looking how I think you want it -- checked in the browser console now that I took a look at your site.

Comment: thanks, I was not aware of `calc`.  In short how does display, effect the box model.